# convert in insert issue sql

Tags: sql, c++builder

I try to insert a varchar of the form 5,777 in a column with real numbers and I get the error "error converting data type varchar to real" and the query fails. When I use convert (real,5,66) the query works but only the number before the decimal is entered. (in that case 5). How can I make it work?

Thanks

Comment: Column type is Varchar or Real ?

Comment: Not really acquainted with C++ but as Markus below suggested, on SQL Server side you use period (.) in place of commas (,) when handling decimal-type figures.

Comment: Better to use a parameterized query instead and let the DB driver handle formatting issues for you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the , by . (in SQL you use english number notation)

Answer (score 0):

try to cast the column into required datatype:

```
 select cast(column as real)
```

Comment: nope.. you need to varchar--> real ? then cast(column as varchar) would help !!

Answer (score 0):

Use the CAST and REPLACE functions

```
SELECT Cast(replace('5,777',',','.') as real)
```

Comment: Using replace on a number with German notation is dangerous as comma and period are switched: Comma is the decimal divider, period is used as thousands separator. So if you replace the comma in e.g. 1.234,56 you might end up with 1.23456 or an error instead of 1234.56.